# Convert list to a 1-column panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with many lines. I am reading each line, splitting each word/number and storing in a list. After this, I am trying to convert this list into a 1-column panda Dataframe.

However after running my code I am getting only one row full of lists. What I need is **1 column with variable number of rows** with some value.

Here is the code snippet I wrote:

```
for line1 in file:
    test_set=[]

    test_set.append(next(file).split())

    df1 = DataFrame({'test_set': [test_set]})
```

My **output** is something like:

```
              test_set
0  [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

**But what I want is**:

```
    test_set
0 1
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 1
7 1
8 1
9 0
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong or how can I implement this? Thanks.

**Input Data Sample snippet**

```
id1 id2 id3 id4
0 1 0 1 
1 1 0 0

id10 id5 id6 id7
1 1 0 1 
1 0 0 1

.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you post what your input data looks like, it's likely it can either be parsed or split in a df which will be quicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out I just had to add this

```
df1 = DataFrame({'test_set': value for value in test_set})
```

But I'm still hoping to get a less costly answer because this will also increase the complexity by another factor or 'n' which is not good enough.

Comment: This cannot be correct if `test_set` is a list. Please show how `test_set` looks like

Comment: This should be fine: df1 = DataFrame({'test_set':  test_set})

Answer (score 16):

You want this instead:

`df1 = DataFrame({'test_set': test_set})`

There is no need to wrap the list again in another list, by doing that you're effectively stating your df data is a list with a single element which is another list.

**EDIT**

looking at your input data you can just load it and then construct your df as a single column like so:

```
In [134]:
# load the data
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""id1 id2 id3 id4
0 1 0 1 
1 1 0 0"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df

Out[134]:
   id1  id2  id3  id4
0    0    1    0    1
1    1    1    0    0
```

Now transpose the df and perform a list comprehension, this will construct your lists and concatenate them using `pd.concat`:

```
In [142]:    
pd.concat([df.T[x] for x in df.T], ignore_index=True)

Out[142]:
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now it's giving the same output but with only less wrapped-around braces like this - `0  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]`

Comment: It's still just one row. :/

Comment: What if you want the dataframe to only have 1 row and `n` columns?

Comment: You can just transpose the result `df = df.T`

Comment: I had to add the call to _pandas_ before the DataFrame:  `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'test_set': test_set})`

Answer (score 7):

This should be fine:

```
df1 = DataFrame({'test_set': test_set})
```

test_set is already a list, you don't have to loop over it so you can add it as a value in pandas.

```
print df1

test_set
0 1
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 1
7 1
8 1
9 0
```

Comment: What if you want the dataframe to only have 1 row and `n` columns?